# Using ffmpeg to record 15 minute segments of a live audio stream

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg

I currently have a code setup to record a live streaming audio file from a given url to an mp3 file until I terminate the program.

```
fmpeg(obj.url)
.noVideo()
.format('mp3')
    .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error(stdout);
    console.error(stderr)
  })
```

I already have it set up so that it will create a new file every time the ffmpeg is called. All I need is a way to have ffmpeg stop, and then start again, every 15 minutes.

I know duration will stop it after 15 minutes, but I don't know of anything that will start the same ffmpeg file again after this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea (untested):

It looks like you might be using [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) already, which is good since it will let you do this:
We can combine ffmpeg's [streaming capabilities](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#outputtarget-options-add-an-output-to-the-command) method with an appending write stream.

`ffmpeg(obj.url)
.output(fs.createWriteStream(path-to-your-file, { 'flags': 'a'}))`